# Creating Read-Only Database/Web Service?

Tags: mysql, web-services, rest

I've created a web service in Netbeans; creating the entities classes from my database.

I was just wondering if i could make mysql database or web service read-only?
The database and web service have been created to retrieve data for my android app; i don't want the app to be able to modify the database, only select using get methods.

I've tried creating roles in my database, deleting the setter methods in webservice but it just causes problems

And advice would be great

Comment: roles in the rdbms that only got read privileges should be a good solution for that case, what kind of problems did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a distinct mysql user account for your webservice that only has read access  (ex. a user with only SELECT privileges to the desired database or tables)?

maybe the most easies way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The Web services will do what they have to do. If your WS is only to get data, then it will just get data, it won't modify it. Also, if the Web Component you're using to expose the Web service doesn't have any methods to insert/update/delete data in your database, then it won't manipulate the data.

In case you have Web Services that can manipulate the data, you have two paths:

1. Don't expose them, so no application could use that Web Service.
2. As @BernhardDenner has posted, create a user in mysql that doesn't have write privileges, and use this user in your Web Component.

Also, I guess your android app shouldn't have a direct communication to the database (that's why you have created your Web Service).